# React-Router noMatch causes asteroid.userId to return falsey

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-router, ddp

Notice the line `Users.methods.isAuthed()` and you can see that its calling `!!asteroid.userId` . My login form works fine, but I'm trying to make a react-router authorization wall which means the router will load the component when the authorization check returns true.

I've investigated further and Users.methods.isAuthed() returns false after passing a 404 url matching this guide: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

**/src/components/PrivatePage.tsx**

```
// almost identical to ./PrivateRoute.tsx

import * as React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import User from '../data/users'
import Page from './Page'

const PrivatePage = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    User.methods.isAuthed() ? (  **// after page 'notFound' this returns false**
      <Page>
        <Component {...props}/>
      </Page>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/redirect',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

export default PrivatePage
```

**/src/data/users.tsx**

```
import asteroid from '../asteroid/'

interface IUsers {
  methods: {
    isAuthed: () => boolean
  }
}

const Users: IUsers = {
  methods: {
    isAuthed() {
      const result = !!asteroid.userId
      console.log({isAuthed: result})
      return result
    }
  }
}

export default Users
```

**/routes/App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import PrivatePage from '../components/PrivatePage'
import Login from './accounts/auth/'
import About from './root/About'
import Home from './root/Home'
import NotAuthorized from './root/NotAuthorized'
import NotFound from './root/NotFound'

interface IProps {}
interface IState {
  isAuthorized: boolean
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  render() {
    const Content = () => (
      <div id='app-content'>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
          <Route path='/redirect' component={NotAuthorized}/>
          <PrivatePage 
            path='/'
            component={Home}
            exact={true}
          />
          <PrivatePage 
            path='/about'
            component={About}
          />
          <PrivatePage component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>        
      </div>
    )

    return (
      <div id='app-container'>
        <Content />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: I think this is caused by not having universal JS setup. the express router doesn't know how to handle the route request and since the server doesn't know how to handle the request, it serves the 404 page and the DDP hiccups